# python to java code conversion for a list datastructure

Tags: java, python

I have a python code like this

```
x = 2
y = 1
g = 0
open = [[g, x, y]]
```

I try to convert it in Java.So I write down like this

```
   ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> open = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> open1=new ArrayList<>();
    open1.add(g);
    open1.add(x);
    open1.add(y);
    open.add(open1)
```

Is that a right approach for conversion? I am little bit confused.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: That's absolutely correct, except for the missing semicolon on the last line ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways that this can be done

You can use Arrays (which are different to ArrayLists), like so:

```
int[] open = {0, 1, 2};
```

For ArrayLists like you have done, you are correct in usin gthe add method, just don't forget the semicolon on the last line:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> open = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> open1=new ArrayList<>();
open1.add(g);
open1.add(x);
open1.add(y);
open.add(open1);
```

You can also do an object oriented approach and use a linked list data structure. Linked lists can be quite efficient in certain situations - heres a link to some docs about them:

https://www.developer.com/java/data/working-with-java-linked-list.html

Comment: open.append([g, x, y]) This is python code. If I write it down in java is it similar to open.add(g); open.add(x);open.add(y);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are creating a 2-Dimensional ArrayList In Java, A list of lists which contains the object type you specified as the generic object type (In-between the <> symbols).

Don't forget to end your statements with a semicolon in java;

You are also going to want to add the generic type parameter when creating a "new" object instance of a list, like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> open = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> open1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer>` or `Integer` on the right hand side hasn't been necessary since Java 6

Comment: Doesn't really matter, it looks cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Looks verbose in my opinion ;)

Comment: Haha, plus 50 for that vocabulary!

Comment: open.append([g, x, y]) This is python code. If I write it down in java is it similar to open.add(g); open.add(x);open.add(y);

Comment: I am not sure that that does in python, as I am not to familiar with the language. However, if append([g, x, y]) "appends", meaning that is adds or inserts, a value into an array index of size "N or greater", then yes, it is similar.

Comment: @EllenaMori Not quite. `open.append([])` is taking a list. Three java `.add()` calls will operate the same as `open.extend([g, x, y])` in Python. There is a difference between adding integers and adding lists into another list

Comment: There are other operations in java that allow you to specify multiple inputs to insert into a list. Overall, I think it is just doing around the same thing if you are working with arrays. Try this, open.addAll(Arrays.asList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4}));